# php exit() function results to memory leaks

Tags: php

I am using a page for ajax requests and inside it i add exit(); function to stop loading the template, since it is an ajax request.

The problem is everytime i add the exit() the memory is not freed. i checked the memory like this:

```
//mypage.php
echo memory_get_usage(); exit(); // This results to memory to climb up for every page refresh.
===============================
//mypage.php
echo memory_get_usage(); // The memory is ok

//For clarification the above codes are executed at different times.
```

What could be the problem? How can i free the memory on exit? Help please Thanks!

Comment: You never get to the second `memory_get_usage();` because you exited the script.

Comment: Memory is automatically freed up on termination of the script, however much was used during execution of the script

Comment: You are checking the memory usage *before* `exit`. Anything after that (including `exit` itself) is not going to affect it.

Comment: This question doesn't deserve upvote.. People upvoted this just because the read memory-leaks in the title :D

Comment: @llnk doesn't really deserve a downvote either...

Comment: What type of memory usage are we even talking about here?

Comment: Can you define freed? Like in the PHP process using more memory on your server? Have you tested this behavior on multiple systems? And what is you just enter the code you posted in your post, still the same behavior, or does the code above not matter at all?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV they are not executed on a single page. I mean i added/removed exit() between executions.

Comment: @Mike actually it goes first to the "start page" index.php and include mypage.php, so there are scripts executed and memory allocated before the code memory_get_usage();

Comment: Guys thank you for your comments and help!

Comment: @JonFabian I see, just one question: Is there a significant difference ? I tested the codes and it showed a difference of ~56 bytes which is insignificant ...

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV yes there is, It climbs up until it reaches Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted :(

Comment: @John Freed: I like to free the memory before or on exit(). Because right now the memory usage files up EVERY page request/refresh. i have 128mb memory limit so dont think its a problem. thanks man

Comment: @JonFabian You should have mentioned it. You may try to increase the allowed memory by setting this on the top of your script `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');` and then try to calculate the difference between the 2 codes.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV mmm. im dont think that could solve the problem, the memory will still climb up until it reaches 256mb :).

Comment: @JonFabian been messing with the garbage collection settings in php.ini?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV i am not sure with that, which setting should i check there? sorry not expert in that area

Comment: @JonFabian wrong person. But what are the values for `session.gc_probability`, `session.gc_divisor` and `session.gc_maxlifetime`? Look in the file outputted by `php_ini_loaded_file()`

Comment: I'm also wondering if you're exponentially incrementing some sort of value and storing it between requests (probably in `$_SESSION`)

Comment: @Mike oh sorry Mike. Here are the settings : session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_probability = 1

Comment: @JonFabian looks fine to me. See my answer. Maybe that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I was able to reproduce your error is by storing a value in `$_SESSION` and doubling its **length** every time. Here is my code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
    $_SESSION['test'] = 'abcdefghij';
}
else {
    $_SESSION['test'] .= $_SESSION['test'];
}
$_SESSION['memory'][] = memory_get_usage();

print_r($_SESSION['memory']);
exit;
```

After refreshing the page 24 times, I finally get it to run out of memory:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 231768
    [1] => 232088
    [2] => 232248
    [3] => 232424
    [4] => 232640
    [5] => 232728
    [6] => 233200
    [7] => 233984
    [8] => 235376
    [9] => 238136
    [10] => 243392
    [11] => 253768
    [12] => 274384
    [13] => 315480
    [14] => 397536
    [15] => 561512
    [16] => 889328
    [17] => 1544952
    [18] => 2855808
    [19] => 5477384
    [20] => 10720400
    [21] => 21206296
    [22] => 42177952
    [23] => 84121128
)
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 83886344 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

You can see that the memory usage increases every time the page is refreshed.

When you tell PHP to `exit`, it doesn't execute anything further in your code. My guess is that somewhere after you do `exit`, you also do something like:

```
$_SESSION['test'] = 'something else';
```

When you `exit` the page, this won't get executed and therefore throws it into an exponentially incrementing loop, increasing the memory usage every time. If you can't find anything like this, I would recommend looking into [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) to get a better picture of what's happening.

Comment: Yes , this is part of the issue, and the main reason is the unclosed ob_start(); and the $_SESSION is part of it. in my render() method of my Template Class. Thanks a lot man!! i gave you the green check :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known aspect of PHP and according to people with definitely much more knowledge than me, it is kind of intentional. Someone had an exactly the same question (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.devel/77918) and it turns out they do it on purpose:

> We do have some intentional leaks where we rely on the pool allocator
>   to wipe things at the end of a request. So I am less concerned about
>   things you see at request termination than I would be if you found one
>   mid-request.

Hope this shines some light on your question.

Comment: Thanks ZolrleQ. il check this.:)

Comment: Hi ZorleQ you suggested zend framework and zend framework setting. I am not using zend :)

Comment: I would expect this to be exactly the same principle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mistaken about what is causing the memory leak. If you try to modify your code to the below then you'll see that nothing runs after the `exit` call.

```
echo memory_get_usage(); exit(); // This results to memory to climb up for every page refresh.

echo "I will never echo". PHP_EOL;
echo memory_get_usage(); // The memory is ok
```

To debug this properly I'd recommend including some extra debug context to all of your inline debugging like this:

```
echo "before database call: ". memory_get_usage() . PHP_EOL;
```

and then from them work out where the memory usage starts climbing

Comment: Hi James, actually the request is transferred first to the "root page" index..php and include mypage.php, so there are scripts and memory allocations before calling memory_get_usage(). thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Guys Thank you for the help, i truly appreciate it. Im lucky i found the issue. It is probably the render() method of my Template Class which contains the ob_start(). So when the exit() function is called in mypage.php(which is included in render()). the output buffer maybe exhausted. Im not sure this could be the problem but i was able to solve the issue by changing the sequence of executing the template->render();

Thanks guys!!

Comment: Probably needs a [`ob_end_clean`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) before the `exit`.

Comment: Solution would be to create your own global function 'CleanExit', which automatically empties all buffers and calls exit.